# Frequency weights in R (multilevel using lme4)

Tags: r, lme4

I'm building a multilevel model with lme4 (two levels: a class and a student level with educational data). I'm using the ICCS 2009 data: http://www.iea.nl/iccs_2009.html). ICCS 2009 advise the use weights. I made a “within-school student weight” as the product of the class and student level weight factors. I also made the sums of the weights equal to the sample size. My question: how can I specify in R that I want to use this weight as a frequency weight. Do I have to use the "survey" package?

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and even more important: [A reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iccs is a complex survey (see chapter 3 of the user guide) and the R survey package cannot (yet) handle multi-level models - you can read the bottom of [this post](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20longitudinal%20study%20of%20adolescent%20health%20%28addhealth%29) for more detail

if you don't care about standard errors, most of the functions in `lme4` have a `weights=` argument that should give you reasonable guesses.. but the standard errors will all be wrong.

the iccs 2009 user guide recommends other software on pdf page 33 of 112.

Comment: True, but I only need to weigh at the student level. I'm not using two weights. I have the within school weight. So how can I do it?

Comment: @JanModus this is a complicated setup that will need `library(survey) ; ?svrepdesign`.  i'll add it to my to-do list for http://asdfree.com/ but it might not happen anytime soon.. and even then you won't be able to construct multi-level models properly.  sorry :/